# Adding months to a date

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a function to add (or decrease) a specific count of months to a date. I'm passing the date as string, in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. In the function below, `$d` is the date i'm passing, for instance `21/04/2017` and `$quant` is the count of months i want to increase or decrease.

```
public static function incMonth($d,$quant) {
        $d = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $d);
        $newDate = strtotime ( $quant . ' months' , strtotime ( $d ) ) ;
        $result = date('d/m/Y',$newDate);
        return $result;
    }
```

I'm calling this function like this :

```
incMonth('21/04/2017','+1');
```

But i'm getting as result `31/01/1970` ! What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can take the code in the dupe and easily modify it to be dynamic and in a function

Comment: Enable proper error_reporting, then PHP will tell you what’s wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Date time is an object and you should use its function to do any data manupilation.

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-12-31');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

so in your case it will be

```
public static function incMonth($d,$quant) {
        $d = new DateTime($d);
        $interval = new DateInterval('P' . $quant.'M');
        $newDate = $d->add($interval);
        $result = date('d/m/Y',$newDate);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (21/04/2017) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character. I'm passing the date in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.